# Angular JS template routing via template-url , rendered templates aren't supporting basic angular expressions

Tags: angularjs, templates, routes

Hi I am building a simple angular app, and am finding that the templates rendered under ng-view( as a part of angular routing by returning template urls... ) don't support angular expressions. To test this I have included {{2+2}} in my index.js file where it returns 4, as well as in my main template which renders "{{2+2}}" as a string...

I am testing this on my localhost..

Anyone have any idea why this is happening?

```
// router.js

var app= angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

// configure our routes
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider

// route for the home page
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl : 'templates/main.html',
        controller  : 'mainController'
    })
});

// index.html
<BODY ng-app="app">

{{2 + 2}}

<ng-view></ng-view>

// main.html
{{2+2}}
```

Comment: Please add some codes.

Comment: Just added.. for a bit more info.. the expression under index.js is evaluating to 4, but in the template rendered between the ng-view tags it evaluates to a string "{{2+2}}"

Comment: Why does your JS file (index.js) contains HTML code?

Comment: @rgwoodiii What error you getting in console ?

Comment: It's not throwing an error, but it's just evaluating angular expressions as strings